# Tem algum problema se eu deixar um arquivo php contendo apenas código HTML?

Tags: php, html

Tenho um arquivo php no meu site que serve como template para uma única página do site, dentro desse arquivo há apenas código HTML, não tem nenhuma tag php `<?php ?>`, nem nada. É como se fosse um arquivo html, mas com a extensão .php

A minha dúvida é a seguinte: Se eu deixar o arquivo como está, vou deixar o site vulnerável a ataques?

Answer (score 7):

Isso por si só não o deixa vulnerável, mas se é um arquivo estático você pode deixar ele como estático, só faz sentido deixar o PHP junto com o HTML quando você precisa renderizar o HTML no servidor. Servir o arquivo como estático também evita a chamada desnecessário do motor PHP para a interpretação do script.

Answer (score 3):

Apenas complementando: O que te deixa vulnerável ou não, são as configurações de segurança do seu servidor e não se a extensão do arquivo é .html ou .php. O problema seria você executar um .php com código malicioso.

Abraços!

Comment: Dei UPVOTE, mas vou fazer 2 OBS... 1. Omitir a extensão do arquivo também é questão de segurança. 2. De nada adianta seu servidor ser seguro se você não tratar as informações de entrada - SQLInjection, XSS e por ai vai

Comment: Correto! Abraço!

Answer (score 3):

Renomeie para .html evitando que o PHP inicie o processo de parse do mesmo!

Quanto a segurança, não, pois como você mesmo disse não existe código PHP, seja ele vulnerável ou não!

Answer (score 1):

Tem dois fatores que implicam nessa pergunta:

**1)** O site seguindo uma padronização de programação, é bom seguir a extensão `.php`.

**2)** A página e/ou site podem ser vulnerável mesmo com ou sem a extensão `.php` isso não interfere na segurança, mas, sim como ela vai para a tela do usuário, se por exemplo, tiver código malicioso ele vai ser vulnerável, porque, o servidor te manda output (saída) `.html`.

Experiência própria, se for `PHP` siga a mesma extensão para todas as páginas.

Answer (score 1):

Não tem não, se for o caso e não tiver problemas (servidor rápido) pode deixar com a extensão `php`, sendo ai passado o parse php para verificar a existência de alguma tag php.

Answer (score 0):

A vulnerabilidade de um arquivo HTML, é a mesma que em um arquivo PHP.

No seu caso, você está lidando com informações "não sigilosas", que poderiam ser visualizadas para "exibição do código fonte". (ou seja, é irrelevante a questão vulnerabilidade)

Sua preocupação com vulnerabilidade deve ser só com: o quão suas senhas são fortes e qual o nível de segurança do servidor onde o site está hospedado.

Tirando isso, não se preocupe com a extensão de arquivo.

Comment: Sua resposta está completamente equivocada... Vulnerabilidade vai **muito³³³** além de senha forte ou fraca...

Answer (score 0):

Se o arquivo apenas contem o template, sem nenhuma senha associado, não existe nenhuma vulnerabilidade, pois um arquivo sem dados confidencias e que não possui permissão de escrita no mesmo e/ou no diretório é como se fosse uma imagem ou algo do tipo. Caso deseje proteger o diretório para ser acessado apenas pelo site, é so definir essa regra no `.htaccess` na pasta.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/pt-br/howto/htaccess.html

O PHP se configurado dentro do `application/x-httpd-php` pode ser executado praticamente com qualquer extensão. O que poderia colocar em risco seria se nesta configuração não aceita-se o PHP dentro HTML e coloca-se o codigo do PHP nele, ai sim poderia exibir uma senha ou algum dado relevante, mas HTML puro não existe nenhum risco.

Comment: HTML puro compreende-se sem nenhuma outra linguagem (PHP/ASP/JSP e afins).